# Determine if a given string is a valid number algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, numbers

Recently encountered this interesting interview question, similar to Leetcode's "Valid Number", but with different constraints. I'm having difficulty developing an algorithm that covers all the edge cases and requirements.

Given a string, write a method that returns true if the string is a valid number or false otherwise.
Only integers and decimals should be considered as valid. In other words,
only characters allowed are digits, "-" and ".".
The string can be very long (think millions of characters) and no built-in function/class
can handle it without overflowing or losing precision.

Some example strings and expected output:

- "13" ---> true
- "3.0" ---> true
- "-7.4" ---> true
- "-13.5" ---> true
- "abc" ---> false
- "123a" ---> false
- "-." ---> false
- "1.0.0.1" ---> false
- "001" ---> false
- ".0" ---> false
- false
- "00.0" ---> false
- "0." ---> false

This is what I have so far:

```java
public static boolean isValidNumber(String s) {
        
        boolean seenDigit = false;
        boolean seenDot = false;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            
            char c = s.charAt(i);
                    
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                seenDigit = true;
            }
            
            else if (c == '.') {
                
                if (seenDot)
                    return false;
                seenDot = true;
                
            }
            
            else if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
                if (i != 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return seenDigit;
    }
```

However, I'm unable to additionally cover these edge cases:

1. isValidNumber("007") == false
2. isValidNumber(".0") == false
3. isValidNumber("000.0") == false
4. isValidNumber("0.") == false

It seems difficult to develop a clean approach that covers all such cases without turning it into spaghetti code, unless I am missing an elegant way of thinking about this problem.

Comment: Use an additional flag that indicates that you have hit a real digit (so trigger on 1-9). The add two conditions: 1) When you encounter `.`, you must have hit a valid digit before 2) When the algorithm ends, you must have hit a valid digit before. 3) Make sure `.` is not the last character and 4) For the `007`, this should actually be considered valid, but if you choose to also fault this case, check that a 0 before a `.` can only come after the first real digit or directly before `.`. You already have that variable that checks if `.` was already encountered.

Comment: Is there any link to test our solution?

Comment: Is "0.00" valid?

Answer (score 2):

> The string can be very long (think millions of characters) and no built-in function/class can handle it without overflowing or losing precision.

Incorrect. `BigDecimal` is built in and can handle millions of characters without overflowing or losing precision.

Trivially, then:

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String s) {
  try {
    new BigDecimal(s);
    return true;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately for you, BigDecimal is less onerous and arbitrary than your ruleset. For example, bigdecimal has no issues with '007'. That is simply 7. It also supports scientific notation (`new BigDecimal("1.23456e4")`), and allows leading + which has no effect.

> It seems difficult to develop a clean approach that covers all such cases without turning it into spaghetti code

Define 'clean'. The question as asked is ridiculously convoluted mess of arbitrary rules that are highly inconsistent.

It **seems** really simple to you (and thus is misleading you into thinking there must therefore be a 'simple' solution) because the arbitrary crazy ruleset so happens to match pretty much to a T precisely what humans consider a normal way of writing a decimally formatted number. The problem is, *humans are arbitrary crazy machines*. You've faked yourself into believing it's simpler than it is.

For example:

- Why are leading zeroes banned? They are decimals, their value is 'correct' (they add 0 to whatever 1000s or whatnot position they are in, that's fine).
- ... except, when the non-fractional part isn't there, they aren't just 'not banned', it is in fact *mandatory* to have a zero. Precisely 1. Not 2, not 0 - no, just 1.
- Why is the dot optional if there is no fractional part?
- Why is a fractional part of all zeroes invalid? "5.00" - everybody knows what that means. In some contexts (such as monetary amounts), it's in fact rather common to render it that way!

and so on.

### So what's the solution?

I'm just taking a wild stab in the dark here, but I bet the question asker is trying to coerce you into writing a state machine solution.

A state machine goes through the input one character at a time, and then treats the combinatory explosion of 'character we found' + 'state we are in' into mapping onto a state (that'll be the state for the next character). Once we get to the end, some states are defined as 'legal' and others are defined as 'not legal'; the system must be in a legal state. That then validates the input.

It's tricky here. For example, just to kick things off:

- we start in the 'START' state.
- START is an invalid end state.
- '-' means we are in the 'START2' state.
- '1-9' means we are in the 'WHOLES' state.
- '0' means we are in the 'WHOLE_ZERO' state.
- All other characters lead to INVALID.

START2 is identical to START, except - is also INVALID.

WHOLES:

- WHOLES is a valid end state.
- '0-9' means we are in WHOLES.
- '.' means we are in DOT.

WHOLE_ZERO:

- is a valid end state.
- '.' means we are in DOT.
- All other characters lead to INVALID.

DOT:

- Is an invalid end state.
- 0 leads to DOT
- 1-9 lead to FRACTIONAL

FRACTIONAL:

- Is an valid end state. Otherwise identical to DOT.

and so on. It's more complicated; presumably, `-0` is invalid, but `-0.5` is valid.

If you want to get fancy about it, you can draw a state machine on a piece of paper - every state is a circle, every transition an arrow. For example, you'd have a circle around the letters 'DOT', then an arrow from DOT pointing to itself with '0' written in the margin, and an arrow going to the circled 'FRACTIONAL' with 1-9 written in the margin of that arrow.

A state machine is a ton of code relative to how simple you appear to think it is supposed to be. But is it *spaghetti*? That's an opinion question, so not something SO is designed to answer. Spaghetti is not a well defined term. State machines are a *very* well known concept, and used all over the place. That doesn't prove that it is or isn't spaghetti of course.

### A second way to go

Instead of a state machine, you can use regular expressions (that's a term you can google; java supports them out of the box). This is also more complicated than it seems, but certainly will lead to less code than a state machine. Possibly code that'll also be harder to read. There are plenty of regular expression tutorials out there. It's much easier to forget to consider a corner case with regexes, and it's far harder to test a failing edge case. I suggest you go with the state machine solution.

Comment: The first part of this answer (about the rules being arbitrary except for matching what we're used to) is very insightful, and I want to upvote for that; but I'm not convinced that a state machine is the cleanest approach here (even if we rule out regexes). On the contrary, I think the first part of your answer fully justifies treating the extra rules about leading zeros and leading/trailing decimal points as separate if-checks, outside the for-loop, rather than trying to shoehorn them into a comprehensive pattern.

Comment: @ruakh 'a boatload of (possibly nested) if/thens is what OP is already aware of; this answer shows 2 different ways to go (state machines, and regexes). You can certainly attempt to write that cavalcade of rules as 'cleanly' as possible (presumably, avoid nesting as much as possible, I guess). I don't think that's what OP was asking for, though.

Comment: How many is "a boatload"? I think only three rules are missing. The only thing that makes it complicated is trying to handle those *inside* the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this is a clear case for using [Java Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). The resulting regular expression is concise and readable; it is much easier to write and maintain than a manually implemented state machine.

Most likely the goal of this question is to check whether you've heard of regex. A state machine might also be acceptable. Doing it entirely "manually" is the most error-prone and tedious.

```java
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("-?(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d+)?");
public static boolean isValidNumber(String s) {
    return NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

Explanation:

- `-?`: Optional minus
- `(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)`: Integer part. `(?:...)` is a noncapturing group. This reads as "either 0 or a digit from 1 to 9 followed by arbitrary digits". *Leading* zeroes are forbidden.
- `(?:\\.\\d+)?`: Optional fractional part: A dot followed by one or more digits.

What you need to wrap your head around here is that instead of excluding invalid input, proper regex only includes valid input.

However, using features such as negative lookaheads, you can also express the exclusion of invalid input conveniently (though the performance of such lookaround may be harder to analyze; in this special case it should be fine though):

```java
private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("-?(?:0|(?!0)\\d+)(?:\\.\\d+)?");
```

This might be considered more readable (if the reader is familiar with the syntax for lookaheads): The `(?!0)` effectively reads as "integer part may not start with a zero". You still need to use `(?:0|...)` to explicitly allow a single zero.

That's it. Only a handful lines of code.

##### Performance

A proper regex implementation will convert a proper regular expression into a finite state machine under the hood for you when compiling the regex, guaranteeing linear time execution.

Many "regex" engines however don't do this; they usually implement "backtracking" instead (in part because this enables more powerful features, like backreferences), which can be much less efficient. Since Java patterns offer such features, we have to assume a backtracking regex engine.

This is not a concern here though; even on a naive backtracking regex engine, this pattern will still match in linear time, since, intuitively speaking, there is always only one valid "choice" the engine can make as it walks through the string; if it makes the "wrong" choice, the matching has to stop a small constant number of steps later. (For greedy quantifiers, it later has to backtrack, trying matching fewer items, but that again stops after a small constant number of steps.)

You could use a "possessive" quantifier as ruakh points out (`[1-9]\\d*+` instead of `[1-9]\\d*`). This will avoid the `\\d*` quantifier backtracking, which doesn't change the overall asymptotic runtime (the backtracking will practically fail in one step, since the next character will be a digit, not a dot), but should slightly improve constant factors. For the part after the dot, you would have to use a lookbehind if you wanted to use a "possessive" quantifier there (but again it's irrelevant for asymptotic runtime).

Comment: +1, though for performance reasons, you may want to use "possessive" quantifiers (`\\d*+` instead of `\\d*`), so that the matcher doesn't have to backtrack all the way back to the beginning if it turns out that something right at the end of the string makes it invalid. (N.B. That requires either your lookbehind approach or some tweaking to avoid swallowing the final `[1-9]` before matching it.)

Comment: (I see that this answer currently claims that backtracking will anyway be bounded to just a few characters; but I think it's mistaken about that.)

Comment: @ruakh Why would the matcher backtrack back to the beginning for the first pattern? Could you give an example where this happens and we get superlinear runtime? I believe that due to the dot acting as a "boundary", everything is in fact fine; there is only one place where the first noncapturing group can end, and that is before the dot, no matter what kind of quantifier is used. Ideally you'd just use a proper regex implementation like Go's or Rust's where matching against the first regex is guaranteed to have linear runtime after compilation anyways ;)

Comment: At least in traditional regex engines, if a quantifier matches *n* times but then the rest of the regex fails to match, then it will backtrack to trying matching just *n*-1 times, then *n*-2 times, etc. And I'm not aware of Java having optimizations to avoid that. (Though it shouldn't give superlinear time in this case, because after it starts backtracking, each step back will fail in O(1) time. So it's O(n) of pure throwaway work, but the total time is still O(n).)

Comment: @ruakh Indeed. It's O(n), but with suboptimal constant factors; your suggestion would indeed improve the constant factors, and my rationale is indeed wrong as currently phrased. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The part after the `\.` is currently not right. It doesn't match `3.0`, which it should, and furthermore it's nowhere a requirement that there should be no trailing `0`.

Comment: @WalterTross you're right, thanks for pointing that out. I skimmed the question and the other answers too quickly (maybe I was subconsciously searching for a pretense to use a negative lookbehind ;)). I'm still not quite sure what *exactly* the question asks because rzwitserloot's answer says something about how the decimal part being all zeroes should be forbidden... Anyways, if you wanted to exclude specifically all zeros yet allow exactly one zero, you could do something like `\.(0*[1-9]0*|0)` (unescaped).

Comment: Re *integer part may not start with a zero.* `"0"` is a valid number, so is `"0.1"`, yet they both start with a `0`

Answer (score 1):

As I noticed my comment on the question was not clear enough, I 'improved' your algorithm to pass all cases, and implemented a simple automated testing, too.

The code could be prettier, but I think suffices the requirements.

### Update:

I now cleaned up the code:

- Added a check for `+ -` only at the first char, so I now do not have to do that in the loop (easier to read, faster alg)
- Removed double `1<c<9` checks and saved it as `isDigit`, removing the ifs and replacing them with conditials `int a = (x == y ? : z)`, improving readability
- Added a comment about the 'accepted' char
- Extended testing for the second algorithm

Code:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumberChecher {

    static private class Pair {
        public final String     StringToParse;
        public final boolean    ExpectedResult;
        public Pair(final String pStringToParse, final boolean pExpectedResult) {
            StringToParse = pStringToParse;
            ExpectedResult = pExpectedResult;
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface TestCaller {
        boolean run(String pCheckString);
    }



    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final ArrayList<Pair> tests = new ArrayList<>();
        tests.add(new Pair("13", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("3.0", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("-7.4", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("-13.5", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("abc", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("123a", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("-.", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("1.0.0.1", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("001", false));
        tests.add(new Pair(".0", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("00.0", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("0.", false));
        tests.add(new Pair("10", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("1", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("0.1", true));
        tests.add(new Pair("0.01", true));

        testAlgorith("Original Algorithm", tests, s -> isValidNumber(s));
        testAlgorith("Cleaner Algorithm", tests, s -> isValidNumber_cleaner(s));
    }

    static private void testAlgorith(final String pTestName, final ArrayList<Pair> pTests, final TestCaller pTestCaller) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning test: " + pTestName);
        int errors = 0;
        for (final Pair p : pTests) {
            final boolean algResult = pTestCaller.run(p.StringToParse);
            if (algResult != p.ExpectedResult) {
                System.out.println("WARNING: mismatch to test string [" + p.StringToParse + "]: expected " + p.ExpectedResult + " but encountered " + algResult);
                ++errors;
            }
        }
        if (errors < 1) System.out.println("All OK!");
        else System.out.println("Still contains errors!");
    }



    public static boolean isValidNumber(final String s) {
        boolean seenDigit = false;
        boolean seenRealDigit = false;
        boolean seenDot = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            final char c = s.charAt(i);

            if ((c < '0' || '9' < c) && c != '+' && c != '-' && c != '.') return false;

            if ('1' <= c && c <= '9') seenRealDigit = true;
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) seenDigit = true;
            if (c == '0' && !seenRealDigit && !seenDot && (i < s.length() - 1 && s.charAt(i + 1) != '.')) return false;

            if (c == '.') {
                if (seenDot) return false;
                if (!seenDigit) return false;
                seenDot = true;

            } else if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
                if (i != 0) return false;
            }
        }

        if (!seenRealDigit) return false;
        return seenDigit;
    }

    public static boolean isValidNumber_cleaner(final String s) {
        if (s == null || s.trim().length() < 1) return false;

        boolean seenDigit = false;
        boolean seenRealDigit = false;
        boolean seenDot = false;

        int startIndex = 0;
        { // check if string starts with + or -
            final char c = s.charAt(0);
            if (c == '+' || c == '-') startIndex = 1;
        }

        for (int i = startIndex; i < s.length(); i++) {
            final char c = s.charAt(i);

            final boolean isRealDigit = '1' <= c && c <= '9';
            seenRealDigit |= isRealDigit;

            final boolean isDigit = isRealDigit || c == '0';
            seenDigit |= isDigit;

            // check for invalid char. only accept 0-9 and '.'; Hint: '+' and '-' are now also invalid, because we jumped over them already
            if (!isDigit && c != '.') return false;

            if (c == '0' && !seenRealDigit && !seenDot && (i < s.length() - 1 && s.charAt(i + 1) != '.')) return false;
            else if (c == '.') {
                if (seenDot) return false;
                if (!seenDigit) return false;
                seenDot = true;
            } // else accept(ignore) c, because it MUST be a digit here [ if (!isDigit && c != '.') return; vs NOT (c == '.') ]
        }

        if (!seenRealDigit) return false;
        return seenDigit;
    }



}
```

Comment: Awesome solution. This line is great:
            
`if (c == '0' && !seenRealDigit && !seenDot && (i < s.length() - 1 && s.charAt(i + 1) != '.'))
 return false`

It simultaneously forbids leading 0s in the integer part, enables 0.xx, and enables leading 0s after dots. I had a hard time writing out simply the logic for where 0s are allowed and this captures it very succinctly. I was wondering what your thought process behind this is? IE how did you go about designing this rule set? Upon reading this it seems very intuitive, but I found it hard to actually try to develop it from scratch.

Comment: Actually this is what I had planned in my mind from the beginning, and when implementing I had forgotten it. So some cases ran me into trouble, and I had to use the debugger, and realized that I had forgotten it. If that whole code had become even a little more convoluted, I'd have implemented all the easy checks first (check if string starts with `.x` or end with it `x.`, plus the +- handling). Then the central alg would have been A LOT easier. I usually write *fail fast - fail early* code. To keep close to your code, I had to draw those checks into the if cascase, using another variable.

Comment: @spacecs I updated my code, added a 'cleaner' version of the algorithm. I guess now it's as clean as it gets. Unless, of course, you prefer the explicit state machines (which usually really are worth investing, especially if minor changes to the requirements are a possibility).

Answer (score 0):

The two clean, general ways to manually write parsing code, which is what you're doing, are to write a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) or [push-down automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), or to [use recursive descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

For a simple job like this one, a state machine is a good choice.  For some reason I've done this many, many times in real work, so I can offer some advice:  The key to making a manually-coded state machine readable and maintainable is to make the states meaningful, so that you can tell by looking what's supposed to happen in each one.

Rely on the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) to determine what your states should be.  That way, each state can be named according to what it's supposed to match -- easy to read -- and you will have the smallest possible number of states.

Putting it all together, your code looks like this:

```java
    // parsing states.  the name is what it matches (Myhill-Nerode)
    // states name MAYBE_* are valid end points, and have negative numbers
    static final int ST_NUMBER = 0;
    static final int ST_POSITIVE_NUMBER = 1;
    static final int ST_MAYBE_FRACTION = -2;
    static final int ST_MAYBE_POSITIVE_OR_FRACTION = -3;
    static final int ST_FRACTION_DIGITS = 4;
    static final int ST_MAYBE_FRACTION_DIGITS = -5;

    public static boolean isValidNumber(final String s) {
        int state = ST_NUMBER;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            final char c = s.charAt(i);
            switch (state) {
                default:
                    // doesn't happen
                    return false;

                case ST_NUMBER:
                    if (c != '-') {
                        --i; //do this char again
                    }
                    state = ST_POSITIVE_NUMBER;
                    break;

                case ST_POSITIVE_NUMBER:
                    if (c == '0') {
                        state = ST_MAYBE_FRACTION;
                    }
                    else if (c >= '1' && c <= '9') {
                        state = ST_MAYBE_POSITIVE_OR_FRACTION;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                    
                case ST_MAYBE_FRACTION:
                    if (c == '.') {
                        state = ST_FRACTION_DIGITS;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                break;

                case ST_MAYBE_POSITIVE_OR_FRACTION:
                    if (c == '.') {
                        state = ST_FRACTION_DIGITS;
                    }
                    else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                        state = ST_MAYBE_POSITIVE_OR_FRACTION;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;

                case ST_FRACTION_DIGITS:
                case ST_MAYBE_FRACTION_DIGITS:
                    // only digits allowed
                    if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                        return false;
                    }
                    state = ST_MAYBE_FRACTION_DIGITS;
                    break;
            }

        }
        // We got to the end of the string.  That's valid
        // if we're in a MAYBE_ state
        return state < 0;
    }
```

As argued in comments below, recursive descent is also a reasonable way to solve this problem.  That would look like this:

```java
    public static boolean isValidNumber(final String s) {
        return matchNumber(s, 0) == s.length();
    }
    
    private static int matchNumber(String s, int pos) {
        int subPos = matchChar(s, pos, '-');
        if (subPos > pos) {
            pos = subPos;
        }
        pos = matchPositiveInt(s, pos);
        if (pos < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        subPos = matchChar(s, pos, '.');
        if (subPos > pos) {
            pos = matchDigits(s, subPos);
            if (pos < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return pos;
    }
    
    private static int matchPositiveInt(String s, int pos) {
        int subPos = matchChar(s, pos, '0');
        if (subPos > pos) {
            return subPos;
        }
        return matchDigits(s,pos);
    }
    
    private static int matchDigits(String s, int pos) {
        int ret = -1;
        for(;pos < s.length(); ++pos) {
            char c = s.charAt(pos);
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                break;
            }
            ret = pos+1;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    
    private static int matchChar(String s, int pos, char c) {
        if (pos < s.length() && s.charAt(pos) == c) {
            return pos + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: He is not writing parsing code; he does not need a DPDA; and he does not need recursive decent either.  And none of these appears in your code. The only state machine required is an NFA or DFA. Chomsky 1956.

Comment: It is scanning, not parsing,and a DPDA of any form, including recursive decent, is complete overkill. There is nothing to push, and nothing to recurse on. Your own code proves it.

Comment: Oh please. Nobody does this. Not even you. And there is no recursion implied in treating those things as non-terminals. What do they recurse on? Chomsky settled this issue 68 years ago.

Comment: @user207421 Add scientific notation and I might very well use recursive descent in real life. Because you've poked me, though, I've added a perfectly fine recursive descent version for this problem to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly trivial regex will do it:

```
return s.matches("-?((0|[1-9]\\d*)(\\.\\d+)?)");
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/F6XoJ4Ru43o6v6) (note that `^` and `$` are in the demo regex because they're needed there, but java `matches()` requires the *whole* string to match so they're *implied*).

The regex means "optional `-` then (either a zero *or* a non-zero and optionally more digits), then optionally a `.` then some digits".

Comment: This validates "0.000". I'm not sure if that is supposed to be valid or not.

Comment: @גלעדברקן At first I thought the same thing - that trailing zeros should not be allowed in decimals, but item 2 of the "true" examples is `3.0`, which has a trailing zero so I assumed that if 1 is allowed, any number should be. To prevent this, instead end the regex with `(\\.\\d*[1-9])?`